# Open an associated `.rds` file in an R / radian terminal by executing `readRDS("RDS_PATH_NAME")`

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, vscode-r

I recently moved from RStudio to VS Code - love it so far, especially for remote sessions!

But: I am missing the feature from R Studio to open an `.rds` file when the file is in the workspace. I know how I can associate the `.rds` file with R, but can I specify that when I want to open it, it runs `readRDS("RDS_PATH_NAME")` in an existing R / radian terminal?